# Why were these 3 questions unilaterally closed?

Tags: discussion

Moderator AJ unilaterally closed

[What happened to the German Panther that the British failed to PIAT twice?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/106803/13434),

[Why did British officers just stand and cheer, while a lone lad was shot in the back trying to fetch an airdrop?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/106802/13434),

[Why didn't Maj Gen Urquhart and his men silence their semi-automatic pistols?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/106801/13434).

At Latin SE, moderators counsel users to ameliorate then re-post old deleted questions, rather than just waiting for 5 undelete votes.

Answer (score 7):

These questions have been asked already and were closed and then deleted by the system.

> At Latin SE, moderators counsel users to ameliorate then re-post old deleted questions, rather than just waiting for 5 undelete votes.

I'd like to ask, did you **ameliorate**?

Those questions were just reposts of closed and deleted questions with no improvement so I put them on hold for the same reason. You're welcome to improve them and then the community can review them and vote accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, at least 2 of these questions were asked before by you and closed/deleted at that time. These seem to be nothing more than reposts and suffer from some of the same problems as before.

I only voted to close one of them (about the airdrop) because it contained **4** questions and thus is **too broad**.

As for the others, I would presume (pending the moderator's comment) that since these were reposts that they were closed for the same reason as the previous versions were.

---

We can't comment on the action of other unrelated sites' moderators but generally we, here on M&TV, prefer to close the question so it can be improved and *then* re-opened to avoid answers being posted to off-topic/sub-standard questions.

Comment: He actually does have a point that if a question is terribly downvoted and closed, it can be preferable to just reask it to give it a fresh start if there was significant improvement, since frankly, this site is quite a bit quicker with downvoting and close-voting than it is with reconsidering these votes once made and an open and improved question with -3 is...kinda crap, even more so if you need the community or moderators to undelete the question in the first place. But of course that only makes sense *if* there actually is significant improvement (not to say *any* at all).